# HTTP_422_UNPROCESSABLE_ENTITY doesn't work with django rest framework

Tags: python, django

It's strange whenever I try to return HTTP_422_UNPROCESSABLE_ENTITY from my django rest api it instead throws 500 with below error whereas same code works when I return 404. Any limitation on this?

```
[Sun Dec 18 05:37:45.314796 2016] [:error] [pid 24535] <rest_framework.request.Request object at 0x7f96cb0a6710> 422 ['profile', 'sig', 'email']
[Sun Dec 18 05:37:45.315550 2016] [:error] [pid 24535] Internal Server Error: /v3/users/signup/
[Sun Dec 18 05:37:45.315561 2016] [:error] [pid 24535] Traceback (most recent call last):
[Sun Dec 18 05:37:45.315564 2016] [:error] [pid 24535]   File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 149, in get_response
[Sun Dec 18 05:37:45.315567 2016] [:error] [pid 24535]     response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
[Sun Dec 18 05:37:45.315570 2016] [:error] [pid 24535]   File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 147, in get_response
[Sun Dec 18 05:37:45.315572 2016] [:error] [pid 24535]     response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
[Sun Dec 18 05:37:45.315575 2016] [:error] [pid 24535]   File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/django/views/decorators/csrf.py", line 58, in wrapped_view
[Sun Dec 18 05:37:45.315577 2016] [:error] [pid 24535]     return view_func(*args, **kwargs)
[Sun Dec 18 05:37:45.315579 2016] [:error] [pid 24535]   File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/django/views/decorators/csrf.py", line 58, in wrapped_view
[Sun Dec 18 05:37:45.315582 2016] [:error] [pid 24535]     return view_func(*args, **kwargs)
[Sun Dec 18 05:37:45.315584 2016] [:error] [pid 24535]   File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py", line 68, in view
[Sun Dec 18 05:37:45.315586 2016] [:error] [pid 24535]     return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
[Sun Dec 18 05:37:45.315589 2016] [:error] [pid 24535]   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 466, in dispatch
[Sun Dec 18 05:37:45.315591 2016] [:error] [pid 24535]     response = self.handle_exception(exc)
[Sun Dec 18 05:37:45.315593 2016] [:error] [pid 24535]   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 463, in dispatch
[Sun Dec 18 05:37:45.315595 2016] [:error] [pid 24535]     response = handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
[Sun Dec 18 05:37:45.315598 2016] [:error] [pid 24535]   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/rest_framework/decorators.py", line 53, in handler
[Sun Dec 18 05:37:45.315600 2016] [:error] [pid 24535]     return func(*args, **kwargs)
[Sun Dec 18 05:37:45.315602 2016] [:error] [pid 24535]   File "/qme/src/queryme/v3/users/views.py", line 37, in signup
[Sun Dec 18 05:37:45.315605 2016] [:error] [pid 24535]     ret = return_request(request=request,error_code=422,params=list(set(valid_params).symmetric_difference(request_params)))
[Sun Dec 18 05:37:45.315607 2016] [:error] [pid 24535]   File "/qme/src/queryme/validity/views.py", line 103, in return_request
[Sun Dec 18 05:37:45.315609 2016] [:error] [pid 24535]     retstatus = status.HTTP_422_UNPROCESSABLE_ENTITY
[Sun Dec 18 05:37:45.315611 2016] [:error] [pid 24535] AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'HTTP_422_UNPROCESSABLE_ENTITY'
```

Error:

> AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'HTTP_422_UNPROCESSABLE_ENTITY'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This return code was added to the Django Rest Framework in version 3.4.1, as explained in [this Pull Request](https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/pull/4291).

Please update your version so you have this code available. Your project probably has a `requirements.txt` file, which has a line like this:

```
djangorestframework==3.3.3
```

You can change it to:

```
djangorestframework>=3.4.1
```

Or fix a newer version, such as:

```
djangorestframework==3.7.3
```